# Troubles converting SVG subset to Java with java tool

Tags: java, svg, codenameone

I am using this tool:

https://github.com/codenameone/flamingo-svg-transcoder

you can read more about it here:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/flamingo-svg-transcoder.html#commento-login-box-container

I used it to convert a svg file and this is the result:

```
/**
* This class has been automatically generated using
* <a href="http://ebourg.github.io/flamingo-svg-transcoder/">Flamingo SVG transcoder</a>.
*/
public class MyImageFromSVGSubset extends com.codename1.ui.Image implements Painter {
private int width, height;
private Transform t = Transform.makeIdentity(), t2 = Transform.makeIdentity();

public MyImageFromSVGSubset() {
    super(null);
    width = getOrigWidth();
    height = getOrigHeight();
}

public MyImageFromSVGSubset(int width, int height) {
    super(null);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    fixAspectRatio();
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

@Override
public void scale(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    fixAspectRatio();
}

@Override
public MyImageFromSVGSubset scaled(int width, int height) {
    MyImageFromSVGSubset f = new MyImageFromSVGSubset(width, height);
    f.fixAspectRatio();
    return f;
}

public Image toImage() {
    Image i = Image.createImage(width, height, 0);
    Graphics g = i.getGraphics();
    drawImage(g, null, 0, 0, width, height);
    return i;
}

private void fixAspectRatio() {
    if(width == -1) {
        float ar = ((float)getOrigWidth()) / ((float)getOrigHeight());
        width = Math.round(((float)height) * ar);
    }
    if (height == -1) {
        float ar = ((float)getOrigHeight()) / ((float)getOrigWidth());
        height = Math.round(((float)width) * ar);
    }
}

@Override
public Image fill(int width, int height) {
    return new MyImageFromSVGSubset(width, height);
}

@Override
public Image applyMask(Object mask) {
    return new MyImageFromSVGSubset(width, height);
}

@Override
public boolean isAnimation() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean requiresDrawImage() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void drawImage(Graphics g, Object nativeGraphics, int x, int y) {
    drawImage(g, nativeGraphics, x, y, width, height);
}

@Override
protected void drawImage(Graphics g, Object nativeGraphics, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    g.getTransform(t);
    t2.setTransform(t);
    float hRatio = ((float) w) / ((float) getOrigWidth());
    float vRatio = ((float) h) / ((float) getOrigHeight());
    t2.translate(x + g.getTranslateX(), y + g.getTranslateY());
    t2.scale(hRatio, vRatio);
    g.setTransform(t2);
    paint(g);
    g.setTransform(t);
}

private static void paint(Graphics g) {
    int origAlpha = g.getAlpha();
    Stroke baseStroke;
    Shape shape;
    g.setAntiAliased(true);
    g.setAntiAliasedText(true);
    /*Composite origComposite = g.getComposite();
    if (origComposite instanceof AlphaComposite) {
        AlphaComposite origAlphaComposite = (AlphaComposite)origComposite;
        if (origAlphaComposite.getRule() == AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER) {
            origAlpha = origAlphaComposite.getAlpha();
        }
    }
    */
    java.util.LinkedList<Transform> transformations = new java.util.LinkedList<Transform>();


    //
    transformations.push(g.getTransform());
    g.transform(new AffineTransform(3.7795277f, 0, 0, 3.7795277f, 0, 0).toTransform());

    // _0

    // _0_0

    // _0_0_0
    shape = new Rectangle2D(0.008569182828068733, 0.0054579987190663815, 6.3905863761901855, 6.390747547149658);
    g.setColor(0xffffff);
    g.fillShape(shape);

    // _0_0_1
    shape = new GeneralPath();
    ((GeneralPath) shape).moveTo(5.0011573, 1.454892);
    ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(4.914109, 1.454892, 4.8439946, 1.526065, 4.8439946, 1.6128483);
    ...
    ...
    //very long sequence of graphical instructions that corresponds to the actual drawing
    ...
    ...
    ((GeneralPath) shape).closePath();

    g.fillShape(shape);

    g.setTransform(transformations.pop()); // _0


    g.setAlpha(origAlpha);
}

/**
 * Returns the X of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 *
 * @return The X of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 */
public static int getOrigX() {
    return 1;
}

/**
 * Returns the Y of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 *
 * @return The Y of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 */
public static int getOrigY() {
    return 1;
}

/**
 * Returns the width of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 *
 * @return The width of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 */
public static int getOrigWidth() {
    return 24;
}

/**
 * Returns the height of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 *
 * @return The height of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
 */
public static int getOrigHeight() {
    return 24;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
    drawImage(g, null, rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
}
}
```

It's Java code to be used in my application (Codename One) but it doesn't work for me.

I put the following code into a working layout:

```
button.setIcon(new MyImageFromSVGSubset(256,256));
```

The image is present because it occupies the right space (256x256) but nothing is drawn.

What is the mistake?

Comment: It draws in white. If your background white? You can change the color in the setColor call.

Comment: @Shai Almog I suppose you refer to g.setColor(0xffffff) call, which I replaced with g.setColor(this.color); color default is 0x000000 now. There is another call, g.setColor(0), I do not know about it. However nothing is draw again upon white background (all is default). What can I check out?

Comment: Try using `toImage()` to see if you can get the right image. You can use scaled then invoke `toImage` to get.a higher resolution image. It's possible something isn't reset properly after SVG drawing but it's hard to debug things like that.

Comment: @Shai Almog Now it's totally black, htmlEditorButton.setIcon(new MyImageFromSVGSubset().scaled(512,512).toImage()); Could it be something related to the painting of background?

Comment: Try that with the white foreground from before and see if that would render the shapes. toImage() should work for that case.

Comment: @Shai Almog Ok, it works but the image is reverted. So I ithink the original code was working, with originall color settings, just the right instruction is the one you suggested, that is, MyImageFromSVGSubset().scaled(512,512).toImage());